# how to play .mpeg, .avi and flv file on html

Tags: video

I have php script from where user can upload the video file. The file may be mpeg, flv and avi.

Should I need to use two player in html on flash player for flv and second embedded MediaPlayer1 for other files.

But how the embedded code will be opened at mac/linux based client side. Is the only way to convert mpeg into flv format??

What about html 5 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to play MPEG (non-MP4) or AVI in a web page, yes, you will need to embed a Media Player, with all the consequent codec, compatibility and stability problems that led people to using Flash video (and latterly HTML5) instead.

Non-Windows machines can play these files if they have suitable plugins and codecs installed, as long as you include a standard `<object type="...">`, or old-school `<embed>` tag inside the IE-specific `<object classid="...">` ActiveX media player embedding.

However, yes, for viewer convenience most video-sharing sites do convert uploaded files into FLV, or—these days more likely—MP4 (which plays on recent Flash players as well as some HTML5 `<video>` implementations), possibly with OGV or WebM as well (for HTML5 browsers that don't implement MP4 for licensing reasons).

Comment: Yes, any user who does not have the codecs used in the video file won't be able to play it. Windows XP includes an MPEG-1 codec but only Vista onwards includes MPEG-2. There are *many* possible codecs that can be used by AVI files. It's a horrible mess. Which is why most sites transcode to Flash/HTML5 video instead.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to play wma, avi, mpg and mp4 video formats on several browsers. Google Chrome and Firefox plays mp4 video with the  tag (`<video src="Video.mp4" controls="controls"> </video>`).Opera and Internet Explorer could not recognise video in  tag. Internet Explorer can play avi video with IE's internal codec. I've used this code for IE:

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" 
name="mediaplayer1" autoplay="false" autostart="false" 
width="900" height="600" loop="false" controls="false" 
allowFullscreen="True" 
src="Video.avi">
</object>
```